# In the jmeter udv how to get it to the value of the parametric

Tags: jmeter

When it was a parameterized value, always take the first value, cannot continue to get the second one  .I just want to dynamic get the list's value to splicing character .
List of params:
[image]
The set of udv:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally came up with the method. Just add a beanshell sampler,and use java to complete slicing charaters.

```
String a = "12343554657";
String b = "\"${__CSVRead(C:\Users\cherry\Desktop\test02.csv,0)}\"";
String c = "123";
String sc = a+"-"+"["+b+"]"+"-"+c;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) into User Defined Variables - it will be executed **only once** during UDV initialization.

You can use __CSVRead() function directly in your script, instead of `${data}` variable - it will read the next line from file each time it will be called.

Check out [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more information on working with functions in JMeter tests.

Comment: sorry,I didn't express clearly.I wanted to ask how to splice characters, for example, i want to splice charaters,like   987546311111555-["${__CSVRead(C:\Users\cherry\Desktop\test.csv,0)}"]-123 . This can not use _CSVRead(). because it can not complete splicing charaters. Thank you for your help.